# single mangement system covers several ML frameworks

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, mxnet

Question: is there any open source project which covers all ML framework management in a single system?

Scenario Description： in some education scenario, many studies and teachers would like to use different ML frameworks such as Tensorflow, Caffe, Mxnet, etc. It's hard for environment guys to prepare all of them one by one.

Comment: it seems like there are *commercial* solutions, e.g. [this one](https://lambdal.com/) - is this the type of solution you are looking? (BTW, I am not affiliated with the company I linked to, and I cannot provide any more details about their solution/how well it actually works, I only post it as a reference to focus the question)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [AWS Deep Learning AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/amis/). The AMI has all the frameworks you mentioned pre-installed for you.

The AMI itself is free of cost. You only pay for the EC2 instances you use.